# PSN and PS plus in Lebanon

Tags: psn

i live in lebanon, if a put my region Lebanon in my PSN account, can i use a lebanese visa card to use PS plus and access store ? Or this service is not yet available in lebanon ? 
Thank you and i appreciate any help in that matter.